# Write email to a professor who is recruiting new PhD students

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application, professorship, email

**Should I send email to a professor who has said on his website that he is recruiting new PhD students through xxx program?** Some people marked this as a duplicate of another question, but I don't really think that question can solve my problem.

Comment: What is xxx program -- is it a valid program? Be specific? Add few more details to make it a proper question.

Comment: Yes. I just want to use xxx to stand for the program's name. Because it varies from university to university, so I didn't give a specific name.

Comment: Yes you should. This is exactly why that message is on the professors website.

Comment: Why would you not?!

Comment: Because usually I will contact the professor for PhD position vacancy. But the professor has said this on his website, so there is no need for me to ask for this. Besides, because students are admitted to the program rather than the lab, and I am interested in several professors' work, so I suppose I should not ask the professor whether I am suitable in the application process. Actually, I am wondering if there is a need for me to contact these professors.@ HEITZ